# If-else condition in JAGS/BUGS

Tags: if-statement, jags, winbugs

I've got large matrix of parameters.

The point is that among many parameters some parameters with arbitrary indexes induce value errors and I'd like to fix them.

The toy example is as follows:

```
foo[3, 2] <- mu[3, 2]    # mu is some (4,4) matrix from data input

for (r in 1:4) {
  for (c in 1:4) {
    foo[r, c] ~ dnorm( mu[r, c], .01 )
  }
}
```

I see some examples like [15414303](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15414303/choosing-different-distributions-based-on-if-else-condition-in-winbugs-jags) and [46730232](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46730232/if-else-statement-for-defining-a-distribution-in-jags), but I cannot wrap my head around the problem how to apply those tricks (or similar) in my case.

Is there a simple way to implement such a logic in JAGS / BUGS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way would be to supply `foo` in the data where all entries beside `foo[3,2]` are missing and `foo[3,2]` is `mu[3,2]`.  Then, the code you have above should work fine (if you remove the definition of `foo[3,2]` in your code). The alternative would be to define the loops around the fixed cell.  For example:

```
for(r in c(1,2,4)){
  for(c in 1:4){
    foo[r, c]  ~ dnorm( mu[r, c], .01 )
  }
}
for(c in c(1,3,4)){
  foo[3, c] ~ dnorm( mu[r, c], .01 )
}
```